# Objective-C object are not destroyed after release message

Tags: objective-c, manual-retain-release

I was confused by such output result of this program.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Human.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Human *human = [Human new];

    [human release];

    [human sayHello];

    return 0;
}
```

The class itself is

```
@implementation Human

-(void)sayHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Deallocated");
   [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The result is [Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2ppR.png)

The main question is why method `sayHello` was executed though object itself was destroyed as its retain count was set to `0` by sending `release` message? What's more important that if I go through the program flow via debugger, the application will crash cause `human` pointer is not an object anymore. What's happening here?

P.S. ARC is turned off

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're correct to expect a failure, but the two consecutive statements don't give the runtime time to reclaim the deallocated object.  Let the run loop finish and reenter with, this: `[human performSelector:@selector(sayHello) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]`, and you'll see the failure that you expect

Comment: Does memory fully release when run loop is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to C!  There are no safety guards here.

When memory is deallocated, the compiler and runtime don't, by default, do anything special other than to mark the memory as available for use by something else.

Whatever is in the memory remains in the memory and, as you've discovered, said memory can still be read from and that can lead to very nasty bugs.

In Xcode, you can turn on zombie detection that would cause this particular bug to be highlighted at runtime by the tools.

There is also malloc scribbling/debugging, which would also catch this.

See here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

Comment: Thanks so much! As I correctly understand you, memory pointer points to can be either object and not. And that’s sometimes will work or sometimes may cause a big problems when it crashes? It strictly depends on how operating system will handle memory that we released?

Comment: Pretty much!  Specifically, when you cause an object to be `deallocated`, nothing clears out the memory that the object resided in.  So, later attempts at messaging it will seemingly work, but it is a ticking time bomb.   ARC defends against this a bit;  things tend to be zeroed out on allocation more proactively.

Comment: Thanks! I got you.